# $R$ is a commutative ring, show $xR[x]$ is prime iff $R[x]$ is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R$ is a commutative ring, show $xR[x]$ is prime iff $R[x]$ is an integral domain and show $xR[x]$ is maximal iff $R[x]$ is a field.

Now, I'm trying to use the theorem that a quotient ring is an integral domain iff the ideal is prime, but this situation is a little different. Once I get one of the arguments down then i'm sure the only will follow by adopting a common strategy of how to turn the proof of why the quotient ring that is formed by using a maximal ideal is a field and adapting it to this situation. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I think it would help if you can show that $R[x]/xR[x] \cong R$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1113677/29335)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f:R[X]\rightarrow R$ defined by $f(P)=P(0)$, it is a morphism and its kernel is $XR[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage proving these lemmas, which are all worth knowing:

[$R[x]/(x)\cong R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574269/show-rx-x-cong-r)

and

[$R/I$ is a domain iff $I$ is a prime ideal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/685431/29335)

and

[$R[x]$ is a domain iff $R$ is a domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1415641/29335)

If you chain these together, you will have your answer to the first question.

The second question about $R[x]$ being a field is **bogus**.  It is never a field since it always has the nonzero proper ideal $(x)$.

---

There is another plausible interpretation of your problem, if you perhaps made a mistake when writing it:

> Prove the following
>
> 1. $R$ is a domain iff $(x)$ is prime in $R[x]$.
> 2. $R$ is a field iff $(x)$ is maximal in $R[x]$.

Those both also follow from the above lemmas.